# Копирование матрицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, матрицы

```
matrices=[]
matrices.append(np.array(matrix))
delta=np.array(matrix)

i=1
while True:
  matrices.append(matrices[i-1].dot(matrices[0]))
  delta+=matrices[i-1]
  if np.diagonal(matrices[i]).sum()!=0:
    break
  if matrices[i].sum()==0:
    break
  i+=1
```

Поменяла, как вы сказали

Вопрос сейчас более точный
Требуется умножать матрицы до тех пор пока либо на диагонали будет какое-то число, либо когда получится нулевая матрица.

При умножении почему-то получаются только единицы и нули, хотя должны быть и другие числа (уже по моим техническим расчетом)

В чём проблема?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: А как и где вы используете `deepcopy`, где код с его использованием? На вид основная проблема тут: `delta=matrix`, это ведь просто копирование ссылки, а дальше вы активно используете `matrices[0]`, а оно у вас меняется, когда вы делаете `delta+= `. Если проинициализировать `delta = np.array(matrix)`, то проблема должна уйти, если я ничего не пропустил. Вроде бы `np.array` нормально делает копию.

Comment: Я попробовала, но по сути от считает неправильно

Comment: Покажите какой-нибудь пример расчёта, который считается неправильно, чтобы было о чём разговаривать.